# I want to trace the activity of my customize link sent via email or on chat to my custome

Tags: email, links, tracking, business

I want to trace the activity of my customize link sent via email or on chat to my customer.

Activity like :

1. whether they opened the link or not?
2. How much time they were on page?

examples:

I have decided to sent business proposal link to Mr.ABC and Mr.XYZ

So, for ABC the link would be like : www.mycompany.com/proposal ....abc...

So, for XYZ the link would be like : www.mycompany.com/proposal ....xyz...

its like link analytic.

**How to go ahead with with it?**

Comment: Did my answer help with your question?

Answer (score 2):

What are you using for your analytics?

Most analytics packages will show where the visitors came from. Regardless of that, they will also show you what landing pages they arrived to, and how long they spent on them.

So if a page visit for `example.com/proposal-abc` appears in your stats then you know it was Mr ABC who came to your site, and if you see `example.com/proposal-xyz`, then you know it's from Ms XYZ.

However, if you're using Google Analytics ([it's free](http://www.google.com/analytics/)), then you can also use it to track visits from there — see [this post by Daniel Waisberg](https://web.archive.org/web/20190309175059/https://plus.google.com/+DanielWaisberg/posts/XDrRoh3GoVP) on how to set up [custom URLs in GA](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033867&rd=1).

Comment: I am not using any analytics, however, i want to know, how to create a simple dynamic customized link generating and link tracking system. Resources, I have : java script developer, asp.net developer.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your initial question then? I would still suggest you check out Google Analytics for link tracking (it runs in JS) instead of creating your own system from scratch (but if you know how to do it, then more power to you!)

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything that prevents you from using Google analytics? Its actually free and you can easily embed it in to your website. This will track any pages that are open and time spent on page and so on.